# Highstock dynamic update issue case

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Expected behaviour
I hope to let the chart also dynamic update when I drag scrollbar and it is not in left boundary or right boundary.
    Thanks for your help.

Actual behaviour
It is a Stationary state when I selected a range via scrollbar and it is not in left boundary or right boundary

Live demo with steps to reproduce highstock dynamic update demo:

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});

// Create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            count: 1,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '1M'
        }, {
            count: 5,
            type: 'minute',
            text: '5M'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        inputEnabled: false,
        selected: 0
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 1000,
                    Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)**

Product version
highstock version : 6.0.7

Comment: Nice description, but still unclear what you're asking?

Comment: Code added properly

Comment: This topic is already discussed here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8044